# Check if LocalTime.now lies in set Durations

Tags: java, compare, intervals, localtime

As stated in the title I want to know if the current time, which I receive over the `import java.time.LocalTime`, lies between set Durations.

In the end I want my program to say "Good morning" if the time lies in the morning, "Good afternoon" if in the afternoon, etc.

These are my durations:

```
Duration Morning = Duration.between(LocalTime.of(05,31),
LocalTime.of(11,30));
Duration Noon = Duration.between(LocalTime.of(11,31),    
LocalTime.of(13,30));
Duration Afternoon = Duration.between(LocalTime.of(13,31), 
LocalTime.of(17,30));
Duration Evening = Duration.between(LocalTime.of(17,31), 
LocalTime.of(22,30));
Duration Night = Duration.between(LocalTime.of(22,31),  
LocalTime.of(05,30));
```

My question is: how do I check if the current time lies in between one of those Durations, and how do I convert it into a String so I can use it to give out different messages?

Comment: You can't. A Duration is not a time range. It's simply an amount of time, like 35 seconds. You can't say if 8:35 is inide a duration of 35 seconds. That makes no sense. Here's the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html. Create your own TimeRange class, containing two LocalTime. Add a contains(LocalTime) method checking if the given time is between the two times stored in the range.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick answer, how exactly do I create a TimeRange? I couldn't find anything about it. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: As I said, it's just a class that you create, with two fields (named start and end, for example), of type LocalTime, and a method contains(LocalTime). Shouldn't be more than 20 lines of code or so.

Comment: Thanks, I will see if I manage to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

As the comment of JB Nizet correctly states, a duration is not an interval, that is - not fixed / anchored on the timeline of 24-hour-clock. Java-8 does not have an interval class. So you have following options:

### Writing a customized interval class

```
class ClockInterval {
    final LocalTime start;
    final LocalTime end;

    private ClockInterval(LocalTime start, LocalTime end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    static ClockInterval between(LocalTime start, LocalTime end) {
        return new ClockInterval(start, end);
    }

    boolean contains(LocalTime time) {
        return !time.isBefore(start) && time.isBefore(end);
    }
}
```

And then (with this extremely minimalistic and incomplete class):

```
ClockInterval morning = ClockInterval.between(LocalTime.of(5, 30), LocalTime.of(11, 30));
ClockInterval noon = ClockInterval.between(LocalTime.of(11, 30), LocalTime.of(13, 30));
ClockInterval afternoon = ClockInterval.between(LocalTime.of(13, 30), LocalTime.of(17, 30));
ClockInterval evening = ClockInterval.between(LocalTime.of(17, 30), LocalTime.of(22, 30));

LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();

if (morning.contains(now)) {
    System.out.println("Good morning.");
} else if (noon.contains(now)) {
    System.out.println("Good midday.");
} else if (afternoon.contains(now)) {
    System.out.println("Good afternoon.");
} else if (evening.contains(now)) {
    System.out.println("Good evening.");
} else {
    System.out.println("Good night.");
}
```

The last else-branch covers any time around midnight based on the fact that all other intervals defined so far connect without any gaps between (see my last note about interval boundaries below).

### Using my library Time4J

**a) First way: class `net.time4j.range.ClockInterval`**

[Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) already offers such a clock interval class. Just use the previous example and change the import statements and following line for current time:

```
PlainTime now = PlainTime.nowInSystemTime();
```

**b) Second way: formatting with customized dayperiods**

```
PlainTime now = PlainTime.nowInSystemTime();

Map<PlainTime, String> dayPeriods = new HashMap<>();
dayPeriods.put(PlainTime.of(5, 30), "morning");
dayPeriods.put(PlainTime.of(11, 30), "midday");
dayPeriods.put(PlainTime.of(13, 30), "afternoon");
dayPeriods.put(PlainTime.of(17, 30), "evening");
dayPeriods.put(PlainTime.of(22, 30), "night");

String p =
  ChronoFormatter.setUp(PlainTime.axis(), Locale.ENGLISH)
  .addLiteral("Good ")
  .addDayPeriod(dayPeriods)
  .addLiteral('.')
  .build()
  .format(now);
System.out.println(p); // Good midday.
```

It should be mentioned that there is also automatical localized support for dayperiods via pattern symbol B. However, the dayperiod schemes used here are not customizable but derived from Unicode data.

```
String p =
ChronoFormatter.ofTimePattern("'Good' B.", PatternType.CLDR, Locale.ENGLISH)
  .with(Attributes.OUTPUT_CONTEXT, OutputContext.STANDALONE)
  .format(now);
System.out.println(p); // Good afternoon.
```

For English, this scheme is used as standard:

> day-period-rules:
>   T0600=morning
>   T1200=afternoon
>   T1800=evening
>   T2100=night

### How to handle interval boundaries?

In general, I recommend to **use a half-open approach for interval boundaries** related to any durations with (clock-)time units. That means, the start of an interval is always inclusive and exactly equal to the time of the open end of the previous interval. Doing so avoids unintentional gaps between intervals, and you can be sure to always match any of the intervals by current time.

But you tried to model the interval boundaries in a different way. For example, you had chosen the morning interval as "05:31/11:30" and the following interval starting at "11:31". If the current time is "11:30:17" by accident (pay attention to the second part!) then such a time would not match any interval.